# Angular NgRx component store. switchMap emits the old value first

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have a flag `isSuccess` in the state to indicate that the entity is successfully set. I want to read the entity's actual value only when `isSuccess` true.

[See the working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngrx-component-store-xzuny3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

To do this I made such expression:

```
this.store.success$
      .pipe(
        filter((isSuccess) => isSuccess),
        switchMap(() => this.store.count$)
      )
      .subscribe((count) => console.log(count));
```

the patch action changes `isSuccess` and `count` simultaneously

```
change() {
    this.setState((state) => ({ count: state.count + 1, isSuccess: true }));
  }
```

But for some reason the old value is emitted first and then the new one.

It is looking very weird to me, because such behavior is not an issue for the global store.

I checked `updated` function source code and see that a ReplaySubject used for the state storage. There is only one `.next` in the func with the next code: `tap((newState) => this.stateSubject$.next(newState)),`. I tried to do the same but with my own `ReplaySubject` and it works as expected. Here is [an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngrx-component-store-nuni8f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)..

What makes the old value to emit and how can I only have my actual value be emitted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause is not in the `updater` function. It is in how the `ComponentStore.select` function build the observable. Internally it uses `shareReplay` operator ([source code](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/10f1146e04d75339532ea55925365ba4736c9c8f/modules/component-store/src/component-store.ts#L277)). And if you add this operator to your   second [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngrx-component-store-jxkdfd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) you will get the same result.

So what exactly happens:

1. The first subscription that occur is in `ngOnInit` where you subscribe on `isSuccess$`
2. Then second subscription happens on the `count$` when the template is compiled (in the html template)
3. It executes pipe of your `count$` select and eventually `shareReplay` remembers the value
4. Then `setState` is executed and sets `isSuccess = true` and `count += 1`
5. Here the most important part starts: isSuccess is pushed and you get notified in your filter and this happens **synchronously**
6. Then you, again, **synchronously** get into your `switchMap` and this operator will **synchronously** subscribe on the `count$`
7. Since `count$` is already cached via `shareReplay` just when you subscribe on it will give you the old result because RxJs hasn't started recalculating it for the existing subscription

If you remove that subscription from html template you will get it work properly. But it not a solution. What you need to do is to make this change with 'isSuccess' to be `async` which means the actual change will be delivered after all synchronous code complete (where a recalculating of your `count$` is a part of it). You can achieve this by placing `.pipe(observeOn(asapScheduler))` It will move the emission of the value to the async queue of the `event loop` and the result will be correct

Here is the [corrected example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngrx-component-store-t5bggc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcounter.store.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are storing the values in the count state, you can use map or startWith but personally I think startWith pipe will do the job - will always emit the first value:

```
switchMap(() => this.store.count$.pipe(startWith(0))) // this will always give you first value.
```

More information:
https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/startWith

Comment: thank you for the answer. but this is not wat I was asking for. count$ can be literally anything. The problem is that when emitted by `switchMap` it gives the the old value first. which was already changed because of `setState`. I am looking for a reason whey it is a case for a component-store

Comment: Apologies for missing that, are you using ReplaySubject for emitting the values?

Comment: I am using ComponentStore of the NgRx to manage the state. I already figured out the issue, please, read my answer if you are interested in it

Comment: Its amazing that you found a solution, but just out of curiosity, did you tried instead of using Replay to use BehaviorSubject?

Comment: Behavior and Replay subjects work the same in my example and produce expected results.